# useEffect is being executed after rendering in a ProtectedRoute

Tags: reactjs

I have an application made in ReactJS that uses Vite (Typescript). My application's route file is being configured as follows:

`index.tsx`:

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "./routes";
import ContractPage from "@pages/ContractPage";
import Login from "@pages/Login";
import ForgotPassword from "@pages/ForgotPassword";
import ChangePassword from "@pages/ChangePassword";

import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";

const Routes = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: '/', element: <Login /> },
  { path: routes.LOGIN, element: <Login /> },
  { path: routes.RECOVER_PASSWORD, element: <ForgotPassword /> },
  { path: routes.CHANGE_PASSWORD, element: <ChangePassword /> },
  //Protected routes below
  { path: routes.CONTRACTS, element: <ProtectedRoute children={<ContractPage />} /> },
]);

export default Routes;
```

Inside my `ProtectedRoute.tsx` I have the following logic:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoginService from '../../services/Login/login.service';

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ children }) => {

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkAccess() {
      const loginService = new LoginService();

      const canAccess = await loginService.checkUserAccess();

      console.log('canAccess', canAccess);

      setIsLoggedIn(canAccess);
    }

    checkAccess();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {alert(isLoggedIn)}
      {isLoggedIn ? children : <Navigate to='/login' />}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

It is important to note that the `checkUserAccess()` method is returning `true`.

When I try to access the contracts route, an `alert` is generated stating that the `isLoggedIn` state is set to `false`, where a short time later I receive a message in the `console` claiming that it was set to `true`.

The problem is that the user has already been redirected back to the login screen.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue you are facing is that the `<Navigate />` is called on initial render. This is because your state is initially `false` and the `{isLoggedIn ? children : <Navigate to='/login' />}` will fall back to the Navigate part.

I would recommend introducing an additional state which keeps the information about the async login check like

```
const [checkedLogin, setCheckedLogin] = useState(false);
```

within your `useEffect` set the `setLogin(true);` as soon as the async login check finished (either with a true or false no matter).

Then for the implementation in the return do something like

```
{isLoggedIn ? children : (checkedLogin ? <Navigate to='/login' />: <></>)}
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The inconsistency arises because the state toggles between its initial value and updated state. To address this in the `ProtectedRoute` file, you can bypass state management and directly store the logged-in user's state in local storage or global state. This can be achieved using tools like Redux's `useSelector` or directly accessing local storage. This approach ensures consistency by persisting the logged-in state across sessions, allowing you to render the component based on the stored state.

Here's how you could modify your ProtectedRoute component to utilize local storage for storing the logged-in state:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoginService from '../../services/Login/login.service';

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkAccess() {
      const loginService = new LoginService();
      const canAccess = await loginService.checkUserAccess();
      localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', canAccess.toString());
    }

    checkAccess();
  }, []);

  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true';

  return isLoggedIn ? <>{children}</> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I hope this helps.